# R: 'Matrix' can not be unloaded, but 'writeMM' method not found

Tags: rna-seq, r

I want to save a sparse and very large `dgcMatrix` onto disc. I read that it could be done with `writeMM` method. So, when I am trying to do that:

```
writeMM(UMI_count, "/home/gene_count_filtered/filtered_dataset")
```

`Rstudio` is giving me an error:

```
Error in writeMM(UMI_count, "/home/gene_count_filtered/filtered_dataset") : 
could not find function "writeMM"
```

Ok, I read that this function is in the `Matrix` package. I installed it, but when I try loading it:

```
library(Matrix)
```

I am getting another error due to other libraries using `Matrix` already on the lower level, as I understand:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
Package ‘Matrix’ version 1.2.11 cannot be unloaded:
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘Matrix’ is imported by 
‘scran’, ‘scater’, ‘SummarizedExperiment’ so cannot be unloaded
```

I also tried just`write.matrix(UMI_count, "/home/nikita/filtered_dataset")`, but got an error:

> Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147

What could be the solution to the problem? I just need to somehow save a very large `dgcMatrix` on disc.

Comment: Which commands did you use to install Matrix? Did you use a fresh (with no environment)  session?

Comment: Nope, but I am having this object and I need to save it. I do not want to restart 10h calculation

Comment: you can install the package in a new instance of R

Comment: But how am I going to save the matrix of the current session? That is the issue

Comment: You open in terminal or from the menu another R session. From there you install the library, then go back to the terminal where you have the data, and try to save. If you find any problem, report the *whole* commands and output here.

Comment: Restarting R should fix this. There’s probably no way around this (you *could* try to manually unload all namespaces that use the `Matrix` package).

Comment: I was skeptical about it but restarting fixed everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I just restarted `Rstudio` as `Konrad Rudolph` suggested, imported `Matrix` library, and then `writeMM` method worked just fine. However, `rownames` were converted into just numbers, but I needed to keep the gene names instead as it was in `dgcMatrix`, so after some search I found a different way of doing that from here:

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata

So, I just did `save()` (and then, to load back - `load()`) and the `rownames` are maintained like I wanted it to be. So, storing it now as `.RData` file.